# 3D list indexing- how to get max(z) for a specific x,y

Tags: python, list, matrix, 3d, indexing

I have a list with 3D index and for each combination (x,y,z) I have a value. I would like to know if there is a way to get the max z for a specific x,y.

Example:

```
 a=defaultdict(list)
 ...
 a = {(0,0,1): 5, (0,0,2): 1, (0,0,3): 4}
```

How to get the max(z) for (x=0,y=0) (which should be 3)?

I need to use this kind of data structure, because I have a dynamic 3 dimensional matrix with unknown z (heterogenous data over Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
`max(b[2] for b in a.keys() if b[0] == 0 and b[1] == 0)`

This uses a generator expression to return the z-coordinate of those values where x and y is 0.

Comment: actually you can omit the lambda part by writing     max([b[2] for b in a.keys() if b[0] == 0 and b[1] == 0])

Comment: The solution is computationally heavy. I have a Big amount of data to process and each time I have to loop over the 3D indexes to check the existence of a specific combination. Is there a faster way to get to the solution? So far, it took me more than 20 minutes to process 10% of the data... pfiou!!

Comment: This you have a lot of data, then I would use numpy. You might improve the speed with `max(b[2] for b in a.keys() if b[0] == 0 and b[1] == 0)`

Comment: @Nras - Good point. Then the whole thing can be a generator expression.

Comment: @user3141990 Did you see my approach? It generates the whole table for every (x,y) combination, thus it only loops once. After that it provides a very fast dictionary lookup. i.e. it will eventually pay off if you this query for many (x,y) combinations.

Comment: The problem is that I am putting data in the structure on the fly, If I have to use the solution I will have to update on the fly also the numpy structure
Thanks for your help!! I find out a solution which is a dict of dict of dict defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict)), a very fast solution allowing to have a 3D indexing over 3 layers X first, Y and finally over Z.
From 20 min for 10% to 2min over all the data =).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), this could be much easier:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 9).reshape((2, 2, 2))
>>> a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
>>> a[0, 0].max()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need this for any of all possible combinations of x and y, i suggest that you should reorder your data, such that a tuple of x and y is a key, whereas the corresponding z is the value. Then you can simply find the max z:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = {(0,0,1): 5, (0,0,2): 1, (0,0,3): 4, (1,0,2): 5}
b = defaultdict(list)
for xyz in a:
    xy = xyz[:-1]
    z = xyz[-1]
    b[xy].append(z)

max(b[(0,0)])
```